# parse API response in JSON using jQuery and html

Tags: jquery, html, api

I'm trying to call a JSON API response and can't seem to displace the response on my website. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Updated:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

   $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/animal/farm", function(data) {

      alert("hi");alert(data.data.writeLatencyMicro);
      alert(data.farm.horses);
      $("ConPerSec").html(JSON.stringify(data));       
   });
 });
</script>
```

...html

```
 <div id="ConPerSec">
 </div>
```

....

The JSON file comes back as
{"farm":{"horses":"2", "cows":"5"}}

Comment: you didn't close window.onload functionw why?

Comment: I don't get it, does it output that string on the screen, or doesn't it output anything? Did you try chaining on a fail() to see if there are errors, such as same origin issues etc

Comment: And what's with the window.onload and the ancient jQuery version!

Comment: Oh, I'm super new at jquery. will look up the new functions.

Comment: If it's just the one item you are updating, I suggest you use id instead of class `<div id="mydiv">` and then the jQuery `$("#mydiv").html(JSON.stringify(data))` unless your intent was to update multiple items on your page that had the class 'ConPerSec'

Comment: I changed the code to [code] $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/animal/house",function(data){alert("hi");} and I don't get an alert..

Comment: Now in your updated code, you are missing `});` at the end, `$(document).ready...` isn't closed. Also `<script>` tag. One advice, before filling inside of functions, make sure putting their closing tags. If you are sharing some part of your code, edit it in here to make sure it doesn't have any mistyping or missing things.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have editted the code above.

Answer (score 1):

If it will always be 1 object / row:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/animal/house", function(data) {
         alert(data.farm.horses);
         alert(data.farm.cows);
});
```